# UI design using struts2

Tags: struts2

I would like to know is there any software for designing jsp page using struts2..like the one in MyEclipse JSP designer...MyEclipse JSP designer is not supporting struts2

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse for designing my jsp pages and it help me with its suggestion ahead features.I also believe that Struts2 only provides tags for general purpose and when it comes to the Designing your jsp page you need some kind of Designing tool like dream-weaver etc.